# Why messageConverter.fromMessage() is not converting an arraylist? java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast

Tags: java, spring, classcastexception, spring-jms

I want to send a JMS message containing a list of sales and receive it via `onMessage()`. As far as I know, `springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter` should play the role of transforming or converting the message so I don't have to create XSDs or extra mapping classes. I mean, I was expecting the test bellow send a message and `(SalesMessage) messageConverter.fromMessage(message)` to be enough to convert and instanciate an object of `SalesMessage`.

Basically, the error is `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to ...SalesMessage`.

My test

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;
MyMessageSender ms;
JmsListenerEndpointRegistry bean;

@Before
public void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {

    context =  new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    ms = context.getBean(MyMessageSender.class);
}

@Test
public void test2() {

    Sale s = new Sale("product_type", 1L);
    List<Sale> l = new ArrayList<Sale>();
    l.add(s);

    SalesMessage sm = new SalesMessage(l, 1);

    ms.sendMessage(sm.toString());

    bean = context.getBean(JmsListenerEndpointRegistry.class);
    for (MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer : bean.getListenerContainers()) {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = (DefaultMessageListenerContainer) listenerContainer;
        container.shutdown();
    }

}
```

MyJmsListener

```
    @Component
    public class MyJmsListener {

         @Autowired
         private MessageConverter messageConverter;

        @JmsListener(destination = AppConfig.QUEUE_NAME)
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            try {
                System.out.println("received: "+message);
//this prints received: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, ..., jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = SalesMessage [sales=[Sale [product_type=produ...ssageType=1]}
                SalesMessage salesMessage = (SalesMessage) messageConverter.fromMessage(message); // <<< here is the focus of my question
                System.out.println("salesMessage: "+salesMessage);
            }
            catch(JMSException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Spring Config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJms
public class AppConfig {
    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "example.queue";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
                new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
                new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        //core poll size=4 threads and max poll size 8 threads
        factory.setConcurrency("4-8");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageConverter converter(){
        return new SimpleMessageConverter();
    }
}
```

SalesMessage class

```
public class SalesMessage  implements Serializable{
    List<Sale> sales = new ArrayList<Sale>();
    int messageType;
    //getters/setters/toString()
```

Sale class

```
public class Sale  implements Serializable{
    private String product_type;
    private Long value;
//getters/setters/toString()
```

Sending message

```
@Component
public class MyMessageSender {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("sending: " + message);
        jmsTemplate.send(AppConfig.QUEUE_NAME, new MessageCreator() {
            @Override
            public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
                return session.createTextMessage(message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*** Edited
Spring Config updqted

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJms
public class AppConfig {
    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "example.queue";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        // core poll size=4 threads and max poll size 8 threads
        factory.setConcurrency("4-8");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
```

*** Edited
 When I print message on Listener side I get

> received: ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:win10-cha-51561-1509914170598-4:2:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:win10-cha-51561-1509914170598-4:2:1:1, destination = queue://example.queue, transactionId = null, expiration = 0, timestamp = 1509914232995, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1509914232995, brokerOutTime = 1509914233010, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@24f339bf, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 1346, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = true, readOnlyBody = true, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false}

and SalesMessage salesMessage = (SalesMessage) messageConverter.fromMessage(message) raises this exception

> org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not find type id property [_type] on message [ID:win10-cha-51561-1509914170598-4:2:1:1:1] from destination [queue://example.queue]

On sending side, I print message

```
SalesMessage [sales=[Sale [product_type=product_type, value=1]], messageType=1]
```

and, here is my complete Application Config updated (I follow the suggestions provided)

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJms
public class AppConfig {
    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "example.queue";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("4-8");
        factory.setMessageConverter(jacksonJmsMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean 
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");


        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return converter;
    }
}
```

And, here is how I am sending the message after last suggestion (significant change was from jmsTemplate.send to jmsTemplate.convertAndSend):

```
@Component
public class MyMessageSender {

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }

    public void sendMessage(SalesMessage  message) {
        System.out.println("sending: " + message);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(AppConfig.QUEUE_NAME, message);
    }
}
```

*** Edited

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Huh?

> ms.sendMessage(sm.toString());
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to ...SalesMessage.

That's because you're sending a `String` (`sm.toString()`) not a `SalesMessage` in JSON form.

Use `jmsTemplate.convertAnsSend(destinationName, sm)`.

The listener container factory also needs the Jackson converter.

Comment: now the exception is org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not find type id property [_type] on message [ID:win10-cha-51561-1509914170598-4:2:1:1:1] from destination [queue://example.queue].

Comment: `received: ActiveMQObjectMessage  ... properties = null,` - it looks like the `_type` property is not being set up correctly on the sending side for some reason; by default it should get set to the class name: `message.setStringProperty(this.typeIdPropertyName, typeId);` where `typeId = object.getClass().getName()`. Check with a debugger that the converter is properly configured and sets up the property.

Comment: I added an image showing all converter property. I am not setting message.setStringProperty anywhere. I understand message.setStringProperty is used when we want to set each field as string. If you look my models (Sale and SalesMessage) you will that SalesMessage is a list of Sale.

Comment: I didn't say you were calling `setStringProperty` - that should be done by the converter if set up properly; however, your screenshot shows the `typeIdPropertyName = null` whereas your configuration has `converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");` - so something is amiss in your configuration. It's the presence of that field that signals to the converter that it needs to set the property with the `SalesMessage` class name. Somehow, you have a different converter instance in your template.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're trying to do here, and you're probably trying to follow this example:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/

However, that example is on Spring Boot. I have a hunch you're not using Spring Boot, based on the face that there's no `@SpringBootApplication` annotation there.

If I'm right about that, you'll need to explitly called the [DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory.setMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/config/AbstractJmsListenerContainerFactory.html#setMessageConverter-org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter-) method with the SimpleMessageConverter you're defining as your bean. I bet Spring Boot probably does this automatically for you, but in your implementation you'll have to do it manually.

So, it should look like:

```
 @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
                new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setMessageConverter(converter());
        factory.setConcurrency("4-8");
        return factory;
    }
```

You'll also need to make sure your object is serializable and you can then do a `jmsTemplate.send` with the object itself. The converter will do the necessary conversion to message payload type for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "in your implementation you'll have to do it manually"? Do you mean "@JmsListener(containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory", destination ...". I am not using Spring Boot for local restrictions. I know the example you mentioned but I am not exactly following such example. I added my Spring Config and my models. I understand my model, which is a arraylist of other object, be serializable since they "implements Serializable".

Comment: That is, you've included the mesaageConverter on your jmsTemplate, but make sure you set in on the listener container factory like in the code snippet in my response.